# Can a MTS 101 2 pin ON-OFF switch rated for VAC be used in a DC circuit?

Tags: switches, ac, dc

I'm currently looking at buying a bunch of MTS 101 rocker switches which are rated for:

AC 125V 6A, AC 250V 3A

For DC the rating is not available

http://www.massuse-relay.com/details/MTSSeries.pdf

The selection was purely considered on "cool factor"

I read something about "arcing" of AC switches in DC circuits, but does this apply on such low voltage circuits as well?
Can I buy and use this or should I really not bother with AC switches in DC circuits (even low powered ones)

The switch would be used to make an 'on/off' toggle for a small electrical device (a small Electric Piano Organ Module which runs on 5v)
- uses 555 IC
- 3x 0.1uF Electrolytic capacitor
- 1x 4.7uF capacitor
- 4ohm 2W speaker
and a bunch of momentary switches and transistors to make sounds.

The other option is SS12D00 or something similar, but even though they work just fine, they look a bit dull in my opinion.
But hey safety > cool factor?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it is just a hobby project it will be fine. Your correct there is a difference between how an AC vs DC switch is build, specifically to reduce arcing. Given your low power and voltages, I would expect this switch to be fine. Maybe you technically risk a reduced life but whatever.

Comment: It probably would work as said above but considering you can get many toggle switches cheaply on ebay, amazon, and other sites, I would recommend just buying ones that are rated for dc.

Comment: Alright thanks for the answers so far.
I ordered a few dc switches just in case.

If I were to make the solder connections to the AC switch and then use shrinking tubing to fully insulate the leads, would that help 'secure' against arcing?

Comment: No, the arc is internal as the contacts separate. Over 1000s of times, it wears the contacts.